# Generate replacement rule from user-defined pattern

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I want to generate a replacement rule from a user-defined pattern. For example, the user provides a list of patterns `{A[i_][j_], BB[k_]}` and a user-defined function `F`, and I hope to generate `{A[i_][j_]:>F[A[i][j], B[k_]:>F[B[k]}`.

I wonder how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

genRules[patterns_, func_] := 
 Thread[patterns :> 
   Evaluate[(func /@ (patterns /. (x_Pattern :> x[[1]])))]]

genRules[{A[i_][j_], B[k_]}, F]

(* {A[i_][j_] :> F[A[i][j]], B[k_] :> F[B[k]]} *)
```

Comment: thanks, works perfectly!